# Transform a string to Vector3

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this string in a MySQL database:

"-1035.43, -2728.861, 13.75664"

How can i transform it to a Vector3 to use it in this function:

```
Vector3 newpos = new Vector3(getChar[15]);
API.setEntityPosition(player, newpos);
```

getChar is the database list, and the 15 is the value.

Comment: Some of us have no idea what a Vector3 is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the `string` and extract the coordinates:

```
float[] newPosCoordinates = getChar[15].Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(x => float.Parse(x)).ToArray();
Vector3 newpos = new Vector3(newPosCoordinates[0], newPosCoordinates[1], newPosCoordinates[2]);
```

Comment: @Roberth, is `getchar[15]` equal to the string value of `"-1035.43, -2728.861, 13.75664"`?

Comment: No, those coordinates changes dinamically

Comment: But are you getting a `string` value with the coordinates from `getChar[15]` that is formatted like the `string` at the beginning of your question?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at `API.setEntityPosition(player, newpos);`, what are the X, Y, Z values of newpos?

Answer (score 2):

```
Vector3 ConvertFromString(string input)
{
    if (input != null)
    {
        var vals = input.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
        if (vals.Length == 3)
        {
            Single v1, v2, v3;
            if (Single.TryParse(vals[0], out v1) &&
                Single.TryParse(vals[1], out v2) &&
                Single.TryParse(vals[2], out v3))
                return new Vector3(v1, v2, v3);
            else
                throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    else
        throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Here's results for the string you provided :
[image]

Comment: I updated my answer with results for the string that you provided as example in the original post. Can you post the string that gives you incorrect results?

Comment: From what I see it's the same string, but anyway those strings change dinamically at any time

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. Make an empty console application, copy ConvertFromString() method there and test it. If it works the issue is with the rest of your code.